# Cannot find TryInto (compilation error) after it was pruned from prelude

Tags: error, compilation, versioning

This Substrate PR removed `TryInto` from the sp_std's prelude: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11136

While attempting to update to `v0.9.19`, which includes this PR, I am encountering this error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `TryInto`
   --> pallets/parachain-staking/src/lib.rs:160:12
    |
160 |     #[pallet::error]
    |               ^^^^^ not found in this scope
    |
    = note: 'sp_std::convert::TryInto' is included in the prelude starting in Edition 2021
    = note: 'std::convert::TryInto' is included in the prelude starting in Edition 2021
    = note: 'core::convert::TryInto' is included in the prelude starting in Edition 2021
help: consider importing one of these items
    |
72  |     use core::convert::TryInto;
    |
72  |     use sp_std::convert::TryInto;
    |
72  |     use std::convert::TryInto;
```

The error suggests that `TryInto` should be included in `Edition 2021`, but this constraint seems to be satisfied. Here is `rustup show` output:

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/stephen/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

nightly-2022-02-20-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.62.0-nightly (082e4ca49 2022-04-26)
```

If I revert the Substrate commit/PR mentioned above, the problem goes away.

I'm able to compile `substrate` itself as well as `polkadot` and `cumulus` at their respective `v0.9.19` branches without any errors.

The exact line of code that produced this error can be found on the Moonbeam repository: https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/bc4d3dbd6159893fab4d9adb265a581d7c502563/pallets/parachain-staking/src/lib.rs#L161

And can be reproduced by compiling that pallet with `cargo build -p parachain-staking`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you provide source of the code that is misbehaving?

Comment: I added a link to the exact LOC that produced the error. It appears to come from any case of `#[pallet::error]` in our repo.

Comment: the Cargo.toml says edition 2018, though. https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/bc4d3dbd6159893fab4d9adb265a581d7c502563/pallets/parachain-staking/Cargo.toml#L5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @apopiak had suggested in the comments, your `Cargo.toml` is still [set as the 2018 edition of Rust](https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/bc4d3dbd6159893fab4d9adb265a581d7c502563/pallets/parachain-staking/Cargo.toml#L5), hence it is not able to locate `TryInto` in the prelude. My guess is that if you change it to 2021, it will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem!